# NP-hard in what parameter?

Tags: terminology

I often read statements such as "the run-time of algorithm X is polynomial **in m and n**". Indeed, when a problem has two parameters, it is possible that the run-time of an algorithm is polynomial in one parameter but not the other one, so if this is not the case, it is important to emphasize that it is polynomial in both parameters.

However, I have never read a statement such as "the problem is NP-hard **in m and n**". A problem is always claimed to be NP-hard, period. My first question is: why? Apparently the same rationale is true here too: a problem may be NP-hard in one parameter, but at the same time, it may have an algorithm with run-time polynomial in the other parameter.

My second question: what is an accurate description of a problem with two parameters: $m$ and $n$, that (1) for a fixed $m$, can be solved in time polynomial in $n$, (2) for a fixed $n$, it is NP-hard (with respect to $m$)?

Comment: The description, "a problem with two parameters: $m$ and $n$, that (1) for a fixed $m$, can be solved in time polynomial in $n$, (2) for a fixed $n$, it is NP-hard (with respect to $m$)" is an accurate description of that problem. Am I missing something?

Comment: A particular "problem is NP-hard in $m$ and $n$" could make perfect sense even if it is ambiguous as indicated by your second question. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Apass.Jack it seems an accurate description to me too, but I have not seen a similar description anywhere. So I thought maybe I was missing something.

Comment: IIRC, input length on the TM is _by definition_ the relevant quantity. It's often handled in a hand-wavy way, in particular if the induced differences are but polynomial (or otherwise irrelevant, in the given context) factors. Parameterized complexity _is_ a thing, though, with its own complexity classes. NP et al. do not permit more than one parameter, by definition.

Comment: One distinction that might help understanding is between an *algorithm* and a *problem*.  An algorithm has a time complexity, but a problem does not have a time complexity per se.  You could however talk about a lower bound on the time complexity of all algorithms for solving a problem, or about the time complexity of a particular algorithm for solving a problem (which is an upper bound).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A problem is always claimed to be NP-hard, period.

Indeed, a problem's definition already contains a specification of its parameters. (See the entries in [Richard Karp's seminal collection of NP-complete problems](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/net.1975.5.1.45) for several examples.) Usually, there is no need to make explicit reference to the parameters *per se*, as they are "automatically scaled" by the input length; for your two parameters $m$ and $n$, for instance, the input could simply be encoded as $0^m1^n$. Hence, for abstract problem instances, it usually suffices to refer strictly to the input length, which is indeed how time complexity is defined (i.e., as the number of computation steps as a function of the input length).

Studying how different requirements on the parameters impact the problem's complexity is the object of study of [parameterized complexity theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_complexity). For example, the set of SAT formulas with $k$ many variables, $k$ being a fixed parameter (i.e., constant), is decidable in polynomial time (in the formula's length); in parameterized complexity terms, this means SAT is *fixed-parameter tractable*. It is only as the number of variables is also allowed to scale (in the input length) that SAT becomes NP-hard.

Comment: Interesting. So the notion of parametrized complexity theory fills the gap.

Answer (score 2):

The question is "**NP**-hard in what parameter?". In fact, we can also ask "**P** in what parameter?", "**NP** in what parameter?" and "**NP**-complete in what parameter?". In fact, a better question might be "**P** or **NP** or **NP**-complete or **NP**-hard in which input?"

#### Formal definitions

Here are the formal definitions of **P**, **NP**, etc as copied and slighted edited from Wikipedia. (In fact, these definition are not very formal. They are just formal enough for this exposition.)

> The class **P** consists of all those decision problems that can be solved on a deterministic sequential machine in an amount of time that is polynomial in the size of the input.
> The class **NP** consists of all those decision problems whose positive solutions can be verified in polynomial time given the right information, or equivalently, whose solution can be found in polynomial time on a non-deterministic machine.
> A **NP**-complete problem is a problem in **NP** to which any other problem in **NP** can be reduced in polynomial time.
> A decision problem $H$ is **NP**-hard when for every problem $L$ in **NP**, there is a polynomial-time reduction from $L$ to $H$.

Readers should review the formal definition of [a decision problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem#Definition) and [a polynomial-time reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_reduction#Many-one_reductions) as well. Note the polynomial-time reduction above means many-one reduction, a.k.a. Karp reduction instead of other kinds of reductions.

#### In which input (in which parameter)?

> A problem is always claimed to be NP-hard, period. My first question is: why? Apparently the same rationale is true here too: a problem may be NP-hard in one parameter, but at the same time, it may have an algorithm with run-time polynomial in the other parameter.

Since we should have specified the input when we define a decision problem, possibly implicitly, there is no need to repeat what are the input when we say that problem is in $P$ or in **NP** or **NP**-complete or **NP**-hard. In fact, we should not mention what are in the input again in order to avoid duplicate data/specification. That is why we see lots of statement like "that problem is **NP**-hard", period.

It is, on the other hand, important to make sure what are the inputs. For example, [a previous version of a question about NP-completeness](https://cs.stackexchange.com/revisions/105517/3) does not specify very clearly the inputs, which in their default format render the problem unlikely in $NP$.  The question was [updated](https://cs.stackexchange.com/posts/105517/revisions) to specify that one of the input values should be given in unary.

#### Family of decision problems

What about a family of decision problems? For example, suppose we have a decision problem $p(s,t)$ for all $(s,t)\in \Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ such that

- for fixed $s$, problem $h_s$ that is the union of all problems of the form $p(s,t)$ is **NP**-hard and
- for fixed $t$, problem $e_t$ that is the union of all problems of the form $p(s,t)$ is in **P**.

We can just describe the situation like the above formally, or more or less. Let $p$ be the union of all $p(s,t)$. Informally, we could also say problem $p$ is in $P$ for fixed $t$ and **NP**-hard for fixed $s$, as shown in the second question.

It is correct to say that $p$ is also **NP**-hard, since $p$ contains, for example, $h_3$ that is **NP**-hard. However, that statement is weaker than "$h_s$ is **NP**-hard for all $s$".

Furthermore, we can have, of course, more than 2 parameters to specify a family of decision problems. The usage will be similar. For example, we could have a family of problems $p(s,t,u)$ which is in **P** for fixed $s$ and $t$ and which is **NP**-hard for fixed $u$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "**NP**-hard with respect to some parameter".

A problem $X$ is **NP**-hard if, for every $Y$ in **NP**, there is a polynomial-time Turing machine computing a function $f$ such that $y\in Y$ if, and only if, $f(y)\in X$. That Turing machine running in polynomial time means that it runs in time $|y|^k$ for some $k$.

Notice that this has nothing to do with any parameter of the **NP**-hard problem $X$, and it can't depend on parameters of the **NP** problem $Y$  because there have to be reductions from *every* **NP** problem.